# cakephp reloading acl/acos/aros after creating a new method in a controller

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

So i've created a new method in a controller, now i need to create the proper acl permissions and acos, aros records etc.  There seems to be no way to "reload" the acl permissions, but to add it "manually" using the api?

I was thinking more of along the lines of a dbsync command or the like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding new methods, you'll need to use buildAcl() - see http://mark-story.com/posts/view/auth-and-acl-an-end-to-end-tutorial-pt-2

I have some code to do updates but it's at home. I'll dig it out later if you like.

Comment: there is also a version in the book, may be more upto date

Comment: As I recall, one or other of them had a bug.